# Maven findbugs missing JRE classes

Tags: java, maven, findbugs

I'm getting a weird message while building a maven project. It doesn't seem to ruin the findbug report, but looks rather annoying.

```
[INFO] Fork Value is true    
[java] The following classes needed for analysis were missing:    
[java]   java.lang.Object    
[java]   java.util.HashSet    
[java]   java.util.HashMap    
[java]   java.io.InputStream    
[java]   java.util.TreeSet    
[java]   java.io.InputStreamReader    
[java]   java.io.BufferedReader    
[java]   java.io.OutputStreamWriter    
[java]   java.io.BufferedWriter    
[java]   java.lang.String    
[java]   java.lang.Character    
[java]   java.lang.StringBuffer    
[java]   java.util.zip.ZipEntry    
[java]   java.util.zip.ZipInputStream    
[java]   java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream    
[java]   java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream    
[java]   java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream    
[java]   java.lang.Throwable    
[java]   java.lang.AutoCloseable    
[java]   java.io.PrintStream    
[java]   java.lang.System    
[java]   java.util.Arrays    
[java]   java.io.FileInputStream    
[java]   java.io.FileOutputStream    
[java]   java.io.IOException    
[java]   java.nio.file.Paths    
[java]   java.lang.StringBuilder    
[java]   java.nio.file.Path    
[java]   java.net.URI    
[java]   java.nio.file.FileSystems    
[java]   java.nio.file.FileSystem    
[java]   java.nio.file.Files    
[java]   java.util.Iterator    
[java]   java.io.OutputStream    
[java]   java.lang.NoSuchFieldError    
[java]   java.io.Serializable    
[java]   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError    
[java]   java.lang.NullPointerException    
[java]   java.lang.Error    
[java]   java.lang.IllegalAccessError    
[java]   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError    
[java]   java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError    
[java]   java.lang.AbstractMethodError    
[java]   java.lang.Exception    
[java]   java.lang.RuntimeException    
[java]   java.nio.file.OpenOption    
[java]   java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException    
[java] Missing classes: 38    
[INFO] Done FindBugs Analysis....
```

How can findbugs plugin miss jre classes?  Is it a bug? I use IntelliJ Idea with default maven settings. In my pom.xml findbugs plugin is configured within `<build>` tag like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <configuration>
         <onlyAnalyze>com.package.my.*</onlyAnalyze>
         <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
         <findbugsXmlOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/findbugs-report</findbugsXmlOutputDirectory>
         <failOnError>false</failOnError>
     </configuration>
     <executions>
         <execution>
             <id>analyze-on-compile</id>
             <phase>compile</phase>
             <goals>
                 <goal>check</goal>
             </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Without seeing your POM and Maven and FindBugs config, it's highly unlikely anybody can help you.

Comment: Consider first upgrading to spotbugs maven plugin .. https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs-maven-plugin which 7 releases ahead of the one you are using.